# GCC - Unused Variable Warning inside Structs

Tags: c++, gcc, c++14

I am searching for a solution where GCC (Arm-Embedded Version) is able to tell me if a variable is not existing at all, when allocated as part of a struct.

The current examples do not warn at all, which i would like to change.

**Example 1:**

Example 1 has 3 variables from a sturct:
var1: assigned but never referenced elsewhere, therefore i want to remove it
var2: not even assigned, makes no sense to waste ram here, remove it
return: assigned and referenced, everything ok.

therefore i would like to get 2 warnings here.

```
struct mydummy_t
{
    bool var1;
    bool var2;
    int return;
};

static mydummy_t dummy;

int main()
{
    dummy.var1 = true;
    dummy.return = 15;
    return dummy.return;
}
```

**Example 2:**

same as example one but now we have a class constructor which initially addresses every variable, but again, not all of them are referenced.

```
struct mydummy_t
{
    mydummy_t() : var1(false), var2(true), return(-1) {}
    bool var1;
    bool var2;
    int return;
};

static mydummy_t dummy;

int main()
{
    dummy.var1 = true;
    dummy.return = 15;
    return dummy.return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking too much of the compiler. How is it to know that this structure is not used in other compilation units, which might reference any or all of those members? (Also, `return` is a reserved word in C++.)

Comment: Correct. The linker never sees the member definitions (they don't require linking) so it can't warn either.

Comment: is there a solution i could help both compiler and linker so they are able to detect such cases?

Comment: @aphardt: No, I don't think so. If you suspect that a member may be unused, just comment it out and see what happens when you try to compile it.